# convert list to columns in spark streaming

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

[image]

Does anyone know how to convert this single-column df (picture) into multiple columns in spark streaming like this :

```
     AT      V       AP     RH      
0  14.96  41.76  1024.07  73.17  
1  25.18  62.96  1020.04  59.08  
2   5.11  39.40  1012.16  92.14  
3  20.86  57.32  1010.24  76.64
```

Comment: version : Spark 3.0.1

Comment: is it dstream or structured streaming ?, can you post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: It’s structured streaming, I’m basically reading from a Kafka stream but I need y to make the transformation above to use as df input to ml model

Comment: Is your array always fixed ??

Comment: Yes it’s always fix

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(
    *[F.col('s_values')[id].alias(i)
      for (id, i) in enumerate(['AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH']) 
     ]
)
```

Comment: i get an error saying F is not  defined , what  F is supposed to be ?